# Maximizing the Euclidean Distance of a Constrained Sum

Tags: optimization, euclidean-domain

Let $ {\bf a} \in \mathbb{C}^{N \times 1}$, where N is a positive integer. Denote the set of phasors ${\bf P}$ as ${\bf P} = \{1,\exp(j 2 \pi/M), \cdots, \exp(j 2 \pi (M-1)/M)\}$, where M is a positive integer. With the collumn vector ${\bf r} = [r_1,\cdots,r_N]^T$, find
$$
{\bf r}^* = \arg \max_{{\bf r}: \; r_\ell \in {\bf P}} |{\bf r}^H {\bf a}| 
$$

The subscripts $( \; )^T$ and $(\;)^H$ denote the transpose and Hermitian transpose operations.

This problem can always be done numerically by a brute force search over all $M^N$ hypothesis, but is there any smart scheme that computes the solution in a smarter way than doing brute force search?

Thanks.

Comment: Let $a_1, a_2,\dots,a_N \in \mathbb C$ and $M>0$ be an integer.
Writing $z = \exp\left(-\frac{2\pi i}{M}\right)$, you wish to find $c_1, c_2,\dots, c_N \in \{0,1,\dots, M-1\}$ that maximizes the absolute value of

$$\sum_{k=1}^N\,a_k\,z^{c_k}.$$

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct